# Acces Violation when trying to use MFC object

Tags: c++, mfc, access-violation

I am working on a MFC project with Kinect that uses a FPS counter. This is a static text. I want this FPS counter to be editted by a method which is also responsible for make the kinect images. So in my main I pass the HWND on to my kinect object like this:

```
kinect->initialize(this->GetSafeHwnd());
```

In my kinect object this thing gets saved:

```
this->hwnd = hWnd;
```

and then this piece of code to initialize the Static Text I want to use:

```
CStatic * MFC_ecFPSCOLOR;
MFC_ecFPSCOLOR = (CStatic *) GetDlgItem(hWnd, TC_FPSCOLOR);
```

And then I want to use it:

```
MFC_ecFPSCOLOR->SetWindowTextW(L"TEST");
```

And here it goes wrong:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x54431C19 (mfc110ud.dll) in KinectMain.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0031004C.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong version of `GetDlgItem`, it returns a handle and not a `CWnd*`. The cast is hiding the error from you.

Comment: So which version of GetDlgItem do I need to use?

Comment: @Cheiron, use the CWnd member function. It doesn't take a hwnd parameter.

Comment: I am quite noobish in this situation, so I still can't get it to function. Can you give a code example?

Comment: I found it! Thanks a lot, I do have one question left: Why does the "wrong" GetDlgItem function exist if it only gives back a handle?

Comment: @Cheiron, because it was there first. It's part of the Windows API, not MFC.